# Error `Cannot read file, ENOENT node:util` while trying to make a binary of a Typescript + NodeJS app with pkg

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, binary

#### Objetive

I'm trying to pack into a binary a Typescript app and the NodeJS executable. I want to be able to distribute the binary in order to avoid to the users the task of installing Node, the dependencies, etc.

#### Environment

- Typescript v4.4.4
- NodeJS v16.13.0
- [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) v5.4.1

#### What I'm doing?

1.- Compile the Typescript to Javascript. The `tsconfig.json` looks like:

> *This step works fine*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Type Checking
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    // Modules
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    // Emit
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "declarationMap": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve",
    "newLine": "lf",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "distribution",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    // Javascript Support
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    // Interop Constraints
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    // Language & Environment
    "lib": [
      "ES5",
      "ES6",
      "ES7",
      "ES2017",
      "ES2018",
      "ES2019",
      "ES2020",
      "ES2021",
    ],
    "target": "ES2021",
    // Compiler Diagnostics
    "listEmittedFiles": true,
    // Output Formatting
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    // Completeness
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "distribution/**/*",
    "types/**/*",
    "binaries/**/*",
  ]
}
```

2.- Try to pack NodeJS and the Javascript files into a binary using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg). For this step, I execute the following command line:

```sh
pkg --out-path binaries .
```

> *This step fails*

The output of that line is the following error:

```sh
> pkg@5.4.1
> Targets not specified. Assuming:
  node16-linux-x64, node16-macos-x64, node16-win-x64
> Error! Cannot read file, ENOENT
  node:util
```

That command line is executed from the root of the project. `pkg` successfully find the `package.json` so it knows where to go to search the first file to start reading. The `package.json` looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "bar moo",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/XXX/YYYY#readme",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/XXX/YYYY/issues"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": {
    "name": "XXX"
  },
  "main": "distribution/main.js",
  "bin": "distribution/main.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/XXX/YYYY.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node distribution/main.js",
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules distribution types binaries",
    "build": "npm ci && npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p tsconfig.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "os-locale": "^6.0.1",
    "yargs": "^17.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cheerio": "^0.22.30",
    "@types/yargs": "^17.0.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "type": "module"
}
```

#### Questions

- How to get rid of the error?
- Am I missing something?

Comment: You've probably seen https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/1309 , right? As far as I know, it's broken with node:* requires, and you'll need to hunt those down and replace with old-style core module requires, like `require('fs')` instead of `require('node:fs')`. Not a viable solution, I know...

Comment: @RobertKawecki didn't see that one. I'm going to review it. Thanks!

Comment: Issue was solved. More info [here](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/1363).